# how to get connection string in .net core to Azure SQL without Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core

I am currently created one Aspnet core C# web api search, which need connected to Azure SQL server.

Anyone know what is the connection String I need to use?

We have some existing stored procedures, and want to call it directly without using Entity Framework Core.

Here is my Azure Data Studio login information.

[image]

Here is the code I am using to get connect to Azure SQL

```
string connectionString = "Server=testServer.database.windows.net;Database=testDB; Authentication=Active Directory Integrated;";
                using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                        try
                        {
                            sqlConnection.Open();

                        }catch(Exception ex)
                        {
                        }
                }
```

Thanks

Comment: Huh? Are you searching for a connection string format? How to obtain a connection string from a config file? Or a library to use to connect to SQL Server?

Comment: I need to know what the connection string will be look like, for normal MS SQL, it will be like  connectionString="Data Source=server;Database=DBName;User ID=username;Password=userpassword;Persist Security Info=True", how about Azure SQL, I am new in Azure and does not know how to build connection string, specially what Authentication Type means in connection string

Comment: Okay, so you're looking for a connection string format? Then why are you asking about Microsoft.Data.SqlClient? [ConnectionStrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/azure-sql-database/) has descriptions for all the common connection string formats, including Azure SQL. All you had to do was find it was search for "azure sql connection string". Microsoft also has [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-dotnet-visual-studio) easily findable from the same search.

Comment: After connection String, I need a way to get return from database, do I just use normal way or need to use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient to handle the data in Dot Net Core? I am also new for Dot Net Core.

Comment: What do you mean by "normal way"?

Comment: Normal way means I am working in asp.net many years and build asp.net web pages use dotnet framework, is that same core and framework to get result back and handle the process? Thanks for the link and I am still not clear which way I need to use for the connection string the link you give me because no one talking about authentication type for MFA support, but I will try all of them and see which one is working for my case.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by "normal way". Are you talking about System.Data.SqlClient? The API surface for that is very nearly the same as Microsoft.Data.SqlClient. Rather than asking about it, you should take it one step at a time, try it, and then if things don't work then you can provide us with a [mcve] and explain what's not working for you.

Comment: Thanks and I will let you know what I do and start from there to next step.

Comment: I try "Server=myserver.database.windows.net;Authentication=Active Directory Integrated;Database=mydatabase";and also try userid with password, all of those does not working

Comment: Describe "not working". You need to be specific about how it's failed, as that can give us clues about what the problem is. What exact error message did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of hours testing and I found one connection string which is working for me.

```
                string connectionString = "Data Source=server.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=dbname;User ID=abc@def.com;Password='testing password'; Authentication='Active Directory Password'";
```

Hope this one can help other people who use **Azure Active Directory - Universal MFA Support**